# Array construction and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, negative-number

I was implementing a routing algorithm in javascript, but when I assign a negative one variable in the array gives me this error: invalid array length.

```
var node = new Array()
node[0] = new Array(6,7)
node[1] = new Array(5,-4,8)
node[2] = new Array(-2) //Here, invalid array length
```

I do not know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are trying to initialize an array that contains only a negative number, use the literal syntax:

```
var a = [-2];
```

The problem with the `Array` constructor is that when it is invoked only with only one argument, this number is used as the `length` of the new array, e.g.:

```
var b = new Array(5);
b.length; // 5
```

I recommend you to stick with the [literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Array_Literals) to avoid those ambiguities.

Comment: That's bitten me before in some legacy code (no I won't accept blame!) where the list of numbers (big database keys, like credit card numbers but not exactly) was in a JSP variable. Strangely, whenever there was just one number in the list, the browser would get an "out of memory" error :-)

Comment: This occurs if the only argument is an integer, It would work with a string.

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare arrays that way!

```
var node = [6, 7];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because one integer argument sets the size of new Array.

Answer (score 1):

The [array constructor documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array) shows the following

```
var arr1 = new Array(arrayLength);
var arr2 = new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN);
```

So, if you use only one parameter, it creates an array of `arrayLength`; otherwise, if you use more than one, it will populate the array with those values.

However, as others have pointed out, it is best use the literal notation *

```
var node = [
    [6, 7], 
    [5, -4 8],
    [-2]
];
```

* Array literal notation is slightly slightly faster than `new Array()`, but that's a micro optimization and not very important in most cases.